# Why isn't autocomplete working with jquery append?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm appending two PHP files to a body content div on a web app I'm developing:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#NotesApp").click(function(){
      $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
        options.async = true;
      });
      $("#NotesApp").remove();
      var request = function(val) { 
        return $.get(val)
      } 
      $.when(request("NavBubbles/Lvl1_Home_LoggedInAs.php"), request("NotesInput.php")) .then(function(a, b) { 
        $("#PageContent").append(a[0], b[0]) 
      }) 
   }); 
 });
```

Within one of these PHP files (NotesInput.php), I have a series of include statements, including an include of a PHP script that echos a JSON-encoded array, and a php file with includes to jQuery and autocomplete:

Example:

```
$(function() {
        var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;
        $( "#inputname" ).autocomplete({
            dataType: "json",
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

This works whenever I run it independently, but not when I append it to another page's body div ...

Comment: Define "not working." Do you see an error in the console? Is it putting the data in the wrong place? Can you `console.log` out the data (`availableTags`) and see the right data?

Comment: no error ... the autocomplete suggestion box isn't popping up onkeyup ...

Comment: yes I can alert(availableTags) and see the right data ...

Comment: I'm also utilizing a site theme that already includes multiple js and css files in index.php (page I'm trying to append this content to) ...

Comment: Please don't post a lot of comments. Compress the information into as few comments as possible. Personally, I'd do `console.log($("#inputname")[0])` and make sure it's binding to the right element.